# Unit test with keras

Tags: python, unit-testing, keras, python-unittest

I do have a machine learning application built on top of Keras. I've done writing methods like `normalize_dataset` , `get_model`, `train_model`, `predict_class` and so on. now I want to write a unit test for this method to assure that they are working correctly but I don't know how to do it.

**Example:**

```py
def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

here I want to write a test for this method to be sure when I added more layer to my model it works just fine as now.

**Update:** much like the first example of this [topic](https://medium.com/@keeper6928/how-to-unit-test-machine-learning-code-57cf6fd81765) but via Keras.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. i did write some tests for other methods like `normalize_dataset` but nothing for `get_model` and `train_model` because i don't know what it should be

Comment: You don't have anything you want to test?

Comment: @KlausD. i have this `get_model` method and i don't know what my test method should be. like when i added more layers (lets say `conv2D` and not adding `Flatten`) how can i check the correctness of my model to converge.